# reading and writing large file size c#

Tags: file, send

im writing a file transfer application to send and receive a large data like 1 GB.. but i think when i read the data from the file and fill it into a byte array it stored on RAM and that would effect on the computer speed .. should i do like :

```
(loop till end of the file)
{
   read 128 MB from the file into byte array
   (loop till end of 128)
   {
       send 1 kb to server
   }
   byte array = null
}
```

if that is right .. 
which is better to do !! beginSend and beginReceive to send the large file or just loop to send the file

i would be glad if you teach me with some code
thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

even 128mb is not a good way .. its better to read a small buffer .. then send it straight to the other side

check it out.

after you send the fileName and the fileSize to other side

this should be common in (server/client)

```
FileStream fs;
NetworkStream network;
int packetSize = 1024*8;
```

Send method

```
public void Send(string srcPath, string destPath)
    {
        byte data;
        string dest = Path.Combine(destPath, Path.GetFileName(srcPath));
        using (fs = new FileStream(srcPath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        {
            try
            {
                long fileSize = fs.Length;
                long sum = 0;
                int count = 0;
                data = new byte[packetSize];
                while (sum < fileSize)
                {
                    count = fs.Read(data, 0, packetSize);
                    network.Write(data, 0, count);
                    sum += count;
                }
                network.Flush();
            }
            finally
            {
                fs.Dispose();
                data = null;
            }
        }
    }
```

Receive method:

```
    public void Receive(string destPath, long fileSize)
    {
        byte data;
        using (fs = new FileStream(destPath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
        {
            try
            {
                int count = 0;
                long sum = 0;
                data = new byte[packetSize];
                while (sum < fileSize)
                {
                    count = network.Read(data, 0, packetSize);
                    fs.Write(data, 0, count);
                    sum += count;
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                fs.Dispose();
                data = null;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Windows will start behaving oddly, if you [begin]Send more than ca. 1MB in one go. This differs between Windows versions, network drivers, shoe size of user and moon phase. Below 1 MB you should be fine.

So, either

```
(loop till end of the file)
{
   read 128 MB from the file into byte array
   (loop till end of 128)
   {
       send 1 MB to server
   }
   byte array = null
}
```

or, if it is really a file

```
SendFile(filename[,...])
```

Comment: actually.. i tried to figure out how SendFile works but i couldn't
because there's no ReceiveFile .. so i couldn't know how to receive the file from the other side.. does it sends by looping till end of the file or what buffer does it use..!! do u have any idea ?